# In python, how to check the end of standard input streams (sys.stdin) and do something special on that

Tags: python, stdin, eof

I want to do something like:

```
for line in sys.stdin:
    do_something()
    if is **END OF StdIn**:
        do_something_special()
```

After a few tries, for now I am doing this:

```
while True:
    try:
        line = sys.stdin.next()
        print line,
    except StopIteration:
        print 'EOF!'
        break
```

Or with this:

```
while True:
    line = sys.stdin.readline()
    if not line:
        print 'EOF!'
        break
    print line,
```

I think both above ways are very similar. I want to know is there a more elegant (pythonic) way to do this?

---

### Early failed tries:

I first tried to catch the `StopIteration` from inside or outside of a `for` loop, but I soon realize that since the `StopIteration` exception is **build into** `for` loop itself, both following code snippet didn't work.

```
try:
    for line in sys.stdin:
        print line,
except StopIteration:
    print 'EOF'
```

or

```
for line in sys.stdin:
    try:
        print line,
    except StopIteration:
        print 'EOF'
```

Comment: Have you found the answer to your question? I am facing the same problem in 2.7. There ought to be a simple solution.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
for line in sys.stdin:
    do_whatever()
# End of stream!
do_whatever_else()
```

It's that simple.

Comment: I tried this one in python 2.7/windows/debian; the loop body does not start immediately after 'enter' is hit, which is not useful. However, the code works as expected in Python 3.

Comment: @Codism: That sounds like input buffering, either in the file object implementation or at the OS level. It's normal. If you want different buffering behavior, there are ways to get that, but it's not the subject of this question.

Comment: This will hang forever if the input dosen't end in a newline.

Comment: @meawoppl: [Can't reproduce.](https://ideone.com/Gf9FZL) As long as the input stream actually ends (instead of just being left open), the loop should terminate. If you're running this from the terminal, you may have to hit Ctrl-D or something to signal end-of-input.

Comment: @user2357112 please add a comment this is correct only for Python 3

Answer (score 15):

Use try/except. [Input](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html?highlight=input#input)

When EOF is read, EOFError is raised.

```
while True:
    try:
        s=input("> ")
    except EOFError:
        print("EOF")
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an iterator

```py
from typing import Iterable
def last_line(itr: Iterable[str]) -> (bool, str):
    last = None
    for line in itr:
        if last is not None:
            yield False, last
        last = line
    if last is not None:
        yield True, last
```

like this

```py
for last, line in last_line(sys.stdin):
    if not last:
        do_something()
    else:
        do_something_special()
```